# How do I set up a Matrox TripleHead2go?

Tags: drivers

Does anybody know how to set up the Matrox TripleHead2go on ubuntu 10.10 or 11.10? I have 3x 22"monitors and a GTS450 Nvidia video card.

Comment: Do you have the TripleHead2go? Are you running in to specific problems setting it up? Or is this a "I have three monitors, should I buy a TH2G?" question?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of it was you plugged it in and it "just worked". The more technical assumption has been the box works out what resolution it can support based on the EDID codes sent from the monitors and then it sends its own EDID code onto the graphics card announcing that and subsets of that resolution. At least, that's how I'd do it if I were making them.

With a Nvidia card, you'd probably want to use the nvidia closed-source driver and `nvidia-settings` to set the resolution.

But I don't own or haven't tested one so I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ux2NRILIJGU).

Maybe this helps? I'll try it myself later on.